# How to bind a typing pattern in Emacs

Tags: vim, emacs

If You have used Vim, You might know about recordings. For example, You can type `q q`, type a sequence of keys, press `q` again, and have Vim perform type that sequence of keys every time You press `@q`. How do I do this in Emacs?

Edit: Is there a reason My answer to My question which I found shortly after posting this question was deleted? Would I not be the best Person to assess whether or not My answer answered My question?

Comment: I have discovered such a behavior is known as an `Emacs macro`. Type `emacs macro` into Your favorite search engine for more information.

Comment: For reference these are called macros in vim and keyboard macros in emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html
Or <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> after this line in emacs *buffer*

```
(info "(emacs)Keyboard Macros")
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to use macros is to type `F3` to start recording a macro and `F4` to finish recording the macro. Then type `F4` as many times as you would like to repeat the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [evil](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) and stay with `q`.